# How to Use Sync Framework with Silverlight Isolated Storage Options

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services, isolatedstorage, microsoft-sync-framework

A google for Sync Framework shows a few blog posts from May 2010 about the possibilities, but I have not seen anyone actually using the Sync Framework + SL Isolated Storage.

Has anyone done this?  Would be awesome if I could reuse my wcf ria service, but that isn't a requirement.

The actual goal is to have a true one-way pull for offline use of a frozen set of data from the server stored in Isolated Storage.

Thoughts?

rusty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight support is supposed to come in Sync Framework V4. Unfortunately, the v4 release has been postponed. Microsoft however will release parts of the V4 CTP as code samples. You may check the [Sync Framework Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/synclab/threads) to see when its made available

Unfortunately, the SL/Isolated Storage feature is not integrated with WCF RIA Services. It uses its own extensions on top of the ODAta protocol and Sync Fx 2.1 though.

Another option you may want to look at is the [WCF Data Services Reference Caching Extensions CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2011/04/13/reference-data-caching-walkthrough.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, for the links.  I have a little time so maybe things will percolate a little more.